# No sound Galaxy Sky

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Have a Galaxy Sky that owes not ring when called, and The other person can hear me, but I cant hear them, even if the phone is on speaker phone. Any help with this would e great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have disabled all sounds! Some Samsung devices have such option where you can disable ALL sound: the phone won't ring, won't play music.. but I don't know if the on-call sound is also muted.

You can check at **Settings > Accessibility >** (if this model supports this feature) **> Disable all sounds**